# How can I get the sum of all odd fibonacci vales in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, fibonacci

I am working through this [Free Code Camp exercise](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/sum-all-odd-fibonacci-numbers).

> Return the sum of all odd Fibonacci numbers up to and including the
>   passed number if it is a Fibonacci number. The first few numbers of the Fibonacci sequence are 1, 1, 2, 3, 5 and
>   8, and each subsequent number is the sum of the previous two numbers.

And here is what I have so far...

Any suggestions?

```
function sumFibs(num) {
    var arr, isFibVal, isEvenVal, sum, i = 0, fibonacci = function (num){
      var a, b, result, fibArr = [1];
        a=0;
        b=1;
        result=b;

        for(var j = 0; j < num; j++){
            result = a + b;
            a = b;
            b = result;
            fibArr.push(result);

       }
      return fibArr;
    },

     isFib = function (val){
     var prev = 0;
     var curr = 1;
     while(prev<=val){
       if(prev == val){
         return true;
       } else {
         return false;
       }
       curr = prev + curr;
       prev = curr - prev;
     }
    },

   isEven = function(someNumber){
         return (someNumber % 2 === 0) ? true : false;
   };

    function sumArray(array) {
      for (
        var
          index = 0,              // The iterator
          length = array.length,  // Cache the array length
          sum = 0;                // The total amount
          index < length;         // The "for"-loop condition
          sum += array[index++]   // Add number on each iteration
      );
      return sum;
    }


      arr = fibonacci(num);
      isFibVal = isFib(num);
      isEvenVal = isEven(num);


    if (isFibVal && !isEvenVal){
        sum  += sumArray(arr);  
}
   return sum;
}
```

All I get back is `undefined` which seems to be weird because i thought this part of my code was pretty cool—using the function values to check vs. in the if statement.

```
  arr = fibonacci(num);
          isFibVal = isFib(num);
          isEvenVal = isEven(num);


    if (isFibVal && !isEvenVal){
        sum  += sumArray(arr);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I won't give you the answer outright since you're going through FCC, but I'll provide you with some hints as to where to look:

See this segment:

```
for(var j = 0; j < num; j++){
    result = a + b;
    a = b;
    b = result;
    fibArr.push(result);
}
```

And this one:

```
function sumArray(array) {
  for (
    var
      index = 0,              // The iterator
      length = array.length,  // Cache the array length
      sum = 0;                // The total amount
      index < length;         // The "for"-loop condition
      sum += array[index++]   // Add number on each iteration
  );
  return sum;
}
```

Also, you probably don't need this segment at all:

```
isFibVal = isFib(num);
  isEvenVal = isEven(num);


if (isFibVal && !isEvenVal){
    sum  += sumArray(arr);
```

Good luck. As someone who has finished a good chunk of the curriculum, I can say that [Free Code Camp](https://freecodecamp.com) is the real deal.

Comment: Thanks for your insight—So the first two are not needed? I know you said the last of three is probably not needed at all. 

As for Free Code Camp, I am really encouraged lately. At first I couldn't break through many of the algorithm challenges, but as of late I have been on streak where I have been getting through them.

Comment: The first two segments need some editing of the logic. The third one is not necessary as far as I'm concerned. You can implement the logic of the third segment into the first two, and perhaps replace that segment with a one liner. Yeah FCC is good. Keep in mind that it's a bit harder for complete beginner. For someone who's completely new, I would suggest starting [codecademy](https://codecademy.com) first.

Comment: Thank you—well I'll keep at it. :)

I've been through codecademy, and the like (Lynda, codeschool etc.) My problem has been practice. Like learning a spoken language you have to start drilling in all the constructs which will help convey your ideas. Since I've been doing that—the actually typing things have changed...

Comment: Keep going! It's a fun, but challenging curriculum. Also you have mentioned the reason why I didn't simply paste you a working solution. This is something that you yourself need to practice thinking through. Debugging is a fundamental skill of any programmer.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close and the other answer is good for pushing you in the right direction, I'll post a different way that does this using native JS functions:

[Example of the code below in JSBin](https://jsbin.com/sufizi/3/edit?js,console)

```
function fibs(n) {
  var f = [0, 1];
  var extraNumber = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    f.push(f[f.length - 1] + f[f.length - 2]);
  }
  // lets check if the passed in number is a fib:
  if (f.indexOf(n) > -1) {
    extraNumber = n;
  }
  console.log(f); // just to check we can cut all the logs later...

  var filtered = f.filter(function(num) {
    // filter out the even numbers
    return num % 2 === 1;
  });
  console.log(filtered);

  var sum = filtered.reduce(function(a, b) {
    // add up whats left
    return a + b;
  });
  console.log(sum);
  return sum + extraNumber;
}
```

Comment: Thanks JH! I'll look it over in the morning!

Answer (score 1):

heres my solution, and i find it to be pretty readable:

```
function sumOddFibs(num) {
  // initialize with 2 because 
  // fib sequence starts with 1 and 1
  var sum = 2;

  var prev = 1;
  var curr = 1;
  var next = 2;

  while (next <= num) {
    prev = curr;
    curr = next;
    next = prev + curr;

    if (curr % 2 !== 0) {
      sum += curr;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You could start by defining variables for the previous number, current number, and total Fibonacci
2. To check for odd numbers, you could use an if statement and use %:

   if (currNum % 2 !== 0){ }
3. If current number is odd, then you add it to the total

   fibTotal += currNumber;
4. To determine the next Fibonacci number you, you will need to add the previous and current number:

   var nextNumber = prevNumber + currNumber;
5. You will need to update the previous number to the current one

   prevNumber = currNumber;
6. Set the current number to the next Fibonacci number in the sequence

   currNumber = nextNumber;

Hope this helps.