# Is there a recursive version for the „sum of odd fibonacci numbers“ task of FreeCodeCamp?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Referring to [How can I get the sum of all odd fibonacci vales in javaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36705648/how-can-i-get-the-sum-of-all-odd-fibonacci-vales-in-javascript) a possible solution derived from FCC looks like that:

```js
function sumFibs(num) {
    let prevNumber = 0;
    let curNumber = 1;
    let result = 0;

    while (curNumber <= num) {
        if (curNumber % 2 !== 0) {
            result += curNumber;
        }
        curNumber += prevNumber;
        prevNumber = curNumber - prevNumber;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I want to broaden the question a bit: Do you see any possibility to use a recursive algorithm for that? I guess there is none. What are your thoughts on that? Is this an „iterative-only“ case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a closure to keep the variables scope safe, then recursion is simple.

I moved the variables into an object so that they can be easily reset using `Object.assign` once the function has completed.

```js
const sumFibs = (() => {
    const o = { p: 0, c: 1, r: 0 };
    const d = Object.assign({}, o);

    const sumFibs = n => {
        if (o.c >= n) {
            const t = o.r;
            Object.assign(o, d);
            return t;
        }
        
        if (o.c % 2 !== 0)
            o.r += o.c;
        
        o.c = o.c + o.p;
        o.p = o.c - o.p;
        
        return sumFibs(n);
    }
    
    return sumFibs;
})();

console.log(sumFibs(100)); // 188
```

Comment: I'm still digesting it in order to understand it fully, thank you. But for the moment I just ran it in jsperf: https://jsperf.com/iterative-vs-recursive-fib-sum/ Interestingly, the very first run the recursive version was about 400% slower, but in all successive runs it's only about 4-10% slower even after fully reloading the jsperf page. What are your results on it?

Comment: I get 10%-12% slower every time.